# How to get all slide information with PowerPoint JS API

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I need to implement a method that will output id and index information of all slides in a presentation. How can I achieve this? The code below doesn't work. I need a code to print id s and indices of every slide.

```html
$("#run").click(run);

async function run() {
  await PowerPoint.run(async function(context) {
    // The slide index is zero-based.
    try {
      let items = context.presentation.slides.load("$all");
      await context.sync();

      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        console.log(items[i]);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please say more than "doesn't work". What do you expect to see and what do you actually see?

Comment: I detailed my question.